# How to fill the second html table by clicking a button from the first table when both of them are on the same page in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel with mySql. I have two table in blade view, one in main div which contains a button to open the second which is in aside div and fill it with data retrieved from the controller. Please find below my code:

my routes

```
// showing list of orders
Route::get('orders/show/all', 'OrderController@showOrders')->name('orders.show.all');
// showing order details
Route::get('orders/details/{id}', 'OrderController@showOrderDetails')->name('orders.details');
```

my controller (OrderController), copied only two functions which have to do with this

```
public function showOrders(){
        $orders = Order::orderBy('total_amount', 'desc')
        ->where('user_id','=', Auth::user()->id)
        ->get();
        return view('orders.undo_sales', compact('orders'));
    }

    public function showOrderDetails($id){
        $ordered_item = Order::findOrFail($id);
        return redirect('orders/show/all', compact('ordered_item'));
    }
}
```

my blade.php file

```
<main class="col-sm-8">

        @include('partials.messages')

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">List of all sales</div>        

            <div class="card-body">

                    <table class="table ">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Order #</th>
                                <th>Order Date</th>
                                <th>Total Amount</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                            @foreach ($orders as $order)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $order->id }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $order->created_at }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ number_format($order->total_amount) }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="{{ route('orders.details', $order->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" onclick="showDiv()">Order details</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

    <aside class="col-sm-4" id="aside">

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Order Details</div>  
            <div class="card-body">

                <table class="table ">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Item Name</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        @foreach ($ordered_item->items as $value)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $value->item_name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($value->pivot->quantity_on_order) }}</td>                                
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>              

            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>
</div>

<script>
    let showDetails = document.querySelector('.show-details')
    let aside = document.querySelector('#aside')

    aside.style.display = 'none'

    function showDiv(){
        aside.style.display = 'block'
    }    
</script>
```

There is no problem with filling the main (first) table with data from the controller. The problem is getting the object returned by the function showOrderDetails($id) to the same view but on a different table and display those records. I tried to dd() the data in the controller on this method and I could see the item_name and the respective quantity. Which proved that there is no problem with this code in blade file:

```
@foreach ($ordered_item->items as $value)
     <tr>
         <td>{{ $value->item_name }}</td>
         <td>{{ number_format($value->pivot->quantity_on_order) }}</td>                                
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

But when I sent to the view I got the error in my view file:

> Undefined variable: ordered_item

Please help me to get the data across.
Thank you.

Comment: You are returning `redirect('orders/show/all', compact('ordered_item'));` instead of a view

Comment: I have changed to ```return view('orders.undo_sales', compact('ordered_item'));``` but got the same error

Comment: You have `$orders` and `$ordered_item` are you sure, you have all your variables when returning the view?

Comment: ```$orders``` is used to fill the main table which has no issue.

Comment: Looks like ```$ordered_item``` does not get to the view but I don't know why

Comment: In both method you need `return view('orders.undo_sales', compact('ordered_item', 'orders'));`

Comment: I think I see what you want... let me make an answer

Comment: Both methods use the same view, but `$ordered_item` is not set when using the `orders/show/all` route. Just use an `@if` block to check if `$ordered_item` is set and only then display it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is to redirect to the same page with an additionnal variable. But it can't work like that.

A simple answer would be this:

**web.php**

```php
Route::get('orders/show/all', 'OrderController@showOrders')->name('orders.show.all');
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function showOrders(){

        $orders = Order::orderBy('total_amount', 'desc')
        ->where('user_id','=', Auth::user()->id)
        ->get();

         // I have added the same condition. I believe, you don't want the user to be able to see all user's orders
         $ordered_item = Order::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
          ->find(request('order_id'));

        return view('orders.undo_sales', compact('orders', 'ordered_item'));
    }
}
```

**blade.php**

```php
....
 <a href="{{ route('orders.show.all', ['order_id' => $order->id]) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Order details</a>
....

@if($ordered_item)
    <aside class="col-sm-4" id="aside">
        @foreach ($ordered_item->items as $value)
            ....
        @endforeach
    </aside>
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works as expected. I accepted as the answer.